# Как запретить переход к следующему элементу по нажатию Tab?

Tags: java, awt

Это учебное задание: нужно написать компоненту "Текстовая область". Я использовал класс Component и переопределил там метод paint(Graphics g), где вывожу построчно данные на Graphics. А также обрабатываю события в KeyListener, чтобы можно было редактировать текст.

Нужно чтобы эта компонента поддерживала табуляцию.
Но когда я нажимаю кнопку Tab, то фокус переходит к следующему элементу. Каким образом можно перекрыть это действие и делать вместо него табуляцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что речь идёт об AWT?

Вам [сюда](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html#FocusTraversal). Конкретно Вас интересуют `focusTraversalKeys`.

Простейшее решение — `Component.setFocusTraversalKeysEnable`. Хотя Sun (теперь уже, видимо, Oracle ;)) рекомендует для текстовых областей не отключать это сочетание клавиш, а заменять на Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: Вообще, в задании можно использовать только awt, не swing. Это может подойти, попробую.

Comment: @krivenko это же и есть AWT, я о чём-то не о том думал :). Исправил.